# Can I apply a Swing look and feel to AWT widgets?

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel

I'm developing on a legacy Java desktop application mixing Swing and AWT controls. I can successfully apply the system look and feel to Swing controls of course, but can I do the same for AWT ones? If not, can I implement some bridge in any way?

Comment: No.  AWT components are native components which derive there look and feel directly from the OS

Comment: Are you saying AWT uses native OS widgets? If that's so, they definitely seem not (it seems a Motif-like theme on both Linux and Windows).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where AWT draws them from (from it's own API or the OS), but they are native widgets like all other "normal" controls in the system (they have their own window handle).  This also means they control there own painting, separate from everything else

Comment: Ok I understand. If you have any references of that you can create an answer.

Comment: Ok, this might be a little hear say, but [The Story Of Awt](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheStoryOfAwt) says *"Java's GuiToolkit had to use the native widgets provided by the host window system, whether Windows, Motif, or the Mac. Mimicking the look-and-feel in Java wasn't good enough; it had to be the real native components."* - Now remember, this could be using particular bindings into particular libraries, which haven't been updated to the newer "wiz-bang" widget libraries

Comment: As of that article, Netscape demanded Java to use native widgets, not just window handles and drawing handled by Java. Later in that article is stated: _Almost as soon as Java 1.0 was released, there was talk of enabling "lightweight components" -- AWT components just like the older ones, with no native peers, drawn and controlled entirely by Java code._ It means that AWT remained completely handled and drawn by Java.
That being said, I guess since AWT doesn't implement a "pluggable" interface like Swing does, doing what I wanted to do is not possible.

Comment: All native widgets have their own "(window) handle", in Java speak, we call this a Peer. So you can find any component and get a "handle" to it (from an OS perspective)

Comment: Yes I understand that. Doing some research about that it seems that on Windows, AWT widgets are better "mimicked" than on Linux. They seem native but they're actually not. @MadProgrammer if you provide an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is "no".  The AWT components are backed by native OS components, either directly (via OS supplied libraries) or indirectly (via AWT based native components).  It's possible that AWT will be linked to "older" component libraries so some of the components won't match the current OS "look and feel", which will be using newer component libraries.

In either case, you can't effect how these components look (and certainly not through Swing's Look and Feel API).

Ok, this might be a little hear say, but [The Story Of Awt](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheStoryOfAwt) says *"Java's GuiToolkit had to use the native widgets provided by the host window system, whether Windows, Motif, or the Mac. Mimicking the look-and-feel in Java wasn't good enough; it had to be the real native components."*